# Non-GPL non-proprietary non-viral-licensed popular video codec?

Tags: video, file-format

FFMPEG is under GPL and there might be issues where a GPL-incompatible program uses it in some ways.

Proprietary codecs like DivX however aren't the option because then I cannot manipulate the format and use royalty free freeware open source converters which I'll need for my own recording purposes via my own devices and video making software.

So which codec isn't from anything from above, but is popular and well played on Windows, Linux, Raspbian and Android (at least in the browser)?

Comment: FFmpeg is LGPL unless you configure it with `--enable-gpl`, `--enable-version3` or `--enable-proprietary` options.

Comment: Please don't spread nonsense FUD like "Viral licenses are scary. They're all sue-happy". It's not relevant to your question and it's plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Most of FFMPEG code is LGPL or "better" - you can build libraries with GPL or LGPL depending of features used.

Take a look at OpenH264 licensing: http://www.openh264.org/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [vp8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8) and [vp9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) video formats owned by google are truly free to use. They are the best video formats at this time that are not encumbered by licensing (GPL or commercial royalties). There are others such as ogg/Theora, although these are older and generally not as well compressed.